# Should cross-posting be mentioned when giving an answer?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I just answered [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872710/pull-alignment-character-position/10873534#10873534) which was also asked [here on BioStars](http://biostars.org/post/show/46223/pull-alignment-character-position/#46227). Should I add in my answer that the question was cross-posted from another site?

Comment: just so it's clear in case people don't check the links, the second one is not a site on the SE network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, if you want to.  But it doesn't have any relevance to our activity here on Stack Overflow, other than to alert other posters that the answer may already exist elsewhere.

It's not like you can close it as a duplicate.